# rake routesが使えなくなりました

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

ruby初心者です。Railsでの開発でrake routesが効かなくなりました。
ググってもわからなかったので質問させていただきます。

```
>Macbook:PetsHuggy UserName$ rake routes
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

「PetsHuggy」は現在作成しているアプリ名で、studyファイルの中で作成しています。
他に作成しているアプリケーションでも同様にrake routesが効かなくなっていました。

先日、Railsを5.0.1⇒5.0.2にアップデートしたのでその際のやり方がまずかったためおこったエラーではないかと考えています。
bundleの再インストールなども試みましたが解決しませんでした。

bundler/setupに問題が？と思いましたが、

```
>/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib
```

に存在していました。

ちなみに(やり方があっているかはわかりませんが)「`--trace`」を試してみろとの記述がありましたので「`rake routes --trace`」を試した結果は下記のとおりです。

```
> rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/Users/UserName/study/PetsHuggy/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:604:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:37:in `<main>'
```

原因・解決法を教えてください。
もし、修正が難しそうであれば(できればクリーンインストールしない方法で)一度環境をリセットして開発環境を再構築する方法を教えて下さい。
お願い致します。

Comment: Markdown記法で記載されるので`>`などが引用ブロックになってしまいます。コードをハイライトさせるにはコードを選択して`{}`ボタンを選択してください。

Comment: rake実行時に bundle exec が付いていないようですが、どのように実行されましたか? 少なくともお使いのRubyとRakeは、bundleしたものではなく、OSに最初からインストールされているもののようです。こちらにもbundlerが正しくインストールされているでしょうか?

Comment: Myaku様　コメントありがとうございます。初めての質問だったのでどうまとめるのが適切なのかわからずに書いていました。

Comment: sakuro ありがとうございます。見直したところ、おっしゃるとおりrbenv上ではなくシステム上のRubyを使用していました。更に見直してbundle installなどを行った結果rakeを利用できるようになりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

(コメントより)

rbenv のものではなく、 Mac に付属の ruby を利用して実行されていたのが原因でした。

rbenv の設定を見直し、 bundle install などを行った結果、問題は解消しました。